# No imprime los arrays de cadenas

Tags: c++, quicksort

he hecho este programa en c++ que ordenar n nombres por orden lexicográfico con el algoritmo quicksort, pero tengo un problema al imprimir los nombres porque el programa no los imprime solo los imprime cuando son dos nombres en el array, hice este mismo programa en c y no hay ningun tipo de error lo intente con `strcpy` y con la funcion  `swap` y ninguna imprime nada, y ya llevo tiempo y no logro solucionar ni ver cual es el error que tengo, si alguien me puede ayudar le agradeceria mucho

A continuacion en el codigo:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;



void quicksort(char nombre[70][70],int izquierda, int derecha)
{
    int i,j,central;
 char aux[70],*pivote;

 i=izquierda;
 j=derecha;

 pivote=nombre[(izquierda+derecha)/2];
 {
        while((strcmpi(nombre[i],pivote)<0)&&(i<derecha)){i++;}
        while((strcmpi(nombre[j],pivote)>0)&&(j>izquierda)){j--;}
        if(i<=j)
        {
            strcpy(aux,nombre[i]);
            strcpy(nombre[i],nombre[j]);
            strcpy(nombre[j],aux);
           //swap(nombre[i],nombre[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
 if(izquierda<j){quicksort(nombre,izquierda,j);}//Ordenamos la sublista izquierda

    if(i<derecha){quicksort(nombre,i,derecha);}//Ordenamos la sublista derecha
 }
 }while(i<=j);

   





}
int main ()
{
    char nombres[70][70];
    int elementos;

    cout<<"Introduce el numero de nombres que desea ordenar alfabeticamente: "; cin>>elementos;
    cin.ignore();

    for(int i=0;i<elementos;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nDigite el nombre "<<i+1<<": ";  cin.getline(nombres[i],70,'\n');

    }

    quicksort(nombres,0,elementos-1);

    for(int i=0;i<elementos;i++)
    {
    
        cout<<i+1<<"-"<<nombres[i]<<endl;

    }





    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te falta un `do`

```
 pivote=nombre[(izquierda+derecha)/2];
 { <<--- JUSTO AQUI
```

Así

```
 pivote=nombre[(izquierda+derecha)/2];
 do {
```

Sin ese `do`, el código se convierte en el siguiente:

```
pivote=nombre[(izquierda+derecha)/2];

while((strcmpi(nombre[i],pivote)<0)&&(i<derecha)){i++;}
while((strcmpi(nombre[j],pivote)>0)&&(j>izquierda)){j--;}
if(i<=j)
{
    strcpy(aux,nombre[i]);
    strcpy(nombre[i],nombre[j]);
    strcpy(nombre[j],aux);
    //swap(nombre[i],nombre[j]);
    i++;
    j--;

    if(izquierda<j){quicksort(nombre,izquierda,j);}//Ordenamos la sublista izquierda

    if(i<derecha){quicksort(nombre,i,derecha);}//Ordenamos la sublista derecha
 }

 while(i<=j) { /* este bucle no hace nada ... y será un bucle sin fin */ }
```